# updatable = false suddenly stopped working

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I was able to update below entity

```
@Table(name = "MyTable")
public class MyInfoLine{

    private CompositeKeyCols id;
    
    @Column(updatable = false)
    private String status;
    
    @Column(updatable = false)
    private LocalDateTime time;


}
```

service to update

```
MyInfoLine myinfo = new MyInfoLine();

CompositeKeyCols key = new CompositeKeyCols();
key.setkey1(key1);
key.setkey2(key2);
key.setkey3(key3);
key.setkey4(key4);
myinfo.setstatus(status);
myinfo.settime(time);
myinfo.setid(key);

myrepository.save(myinfo);
```

Earlier it used to update `status and time` fields in table with `(updatable = false)`, but suddenly stopped updating in table. While running I can see only `Select` query on console but not the `update` query.

My first doubt is, why even earlier it allowed to update with `@Column(updatable = false)` ? Read online, but still not cleared.

`second`, when I change `@Column(updatable = false) > @Column(updatable = true)`, it works fine.

`third`, what could go wrong that it suddenly stopped updating while @Column(updatable = false) ? In debugger I can see that all values are assigned properly to `myinfo` so that it could update.

please share suggestions.

```
There is no change in code except setting @Column(updatable = true) after same coding stopped working, earlier it was @Column(updatable = false)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question correctly.  Are you saying that it works correctly now (that is, `updatable=true` allows it to update, but `updatable=false` doesn't), but earlier worked incorrectly?  If so, I don't know how to help you, without seeing what the earlier, incorrect code looked like.  There's no way for me to tell what it was you unwittingly changed.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem, question updated

Comment: I still don't understand your question for exactly the same reasons as @DawoodibnKareem Please clarify what you are asking. Are you sure you are remembering the difference between insert and update?

Comment: @tgdavies which part you dont understand ?

Comment: Sophia, you changed _something_, even if you can't remember changing anything.  And there's no way anyone reading this question is going to be able to know what it was.  I don't think you're going to get any kind of useful answer.  Fortunately, it sounds like everything's now working correctly.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem, okiee, but can you please share how come @Column(updatable = false) allows to update fields in table ?

Comment: It doesn't.  You can insert values into a column with `updatable=false`, but you can't update them through JPA.

Comment: so if key cols value matches, then it should not insert....right ?

Comment: You haven't specified that the key columns are actually the database key, so JPA won't stop you inserting duplicate keys.  However, it's common practice to set up the database with a uniqueness constraint on the columns that are used as a key.  That way, the database itself rejects any duplicate inserts.